# Can I use Build Environment Variables in Netlify with Create-React-App?

Tags: environment-variables, create-react-app, netlify

How do I use Build Environment Variables in Netlify with Create-React-App?

Comment: A simple google search yielded this: https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/#build-environment-variables

Answer (score 40):

You **CAN** use environment variables in your `create-react-app` on Netlify, but all the build constraints of the Create React App will still apply.

- By default you will have NODE_ENV defined for you
- Any other environment variables starting with `REACT_APP_` will be available
- Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored
- Changing any environment variables will require you to trigger a new build/deploy

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** No environment variables can be accessed from a `create-react-app` dynamically from the browser hosted on Netlify! They must be accessed at build time to be used in the static site.

---

From an [example `create-react-app` repo](https://github.com/talves/netlify-cra-env-vars) hosted on Netlify:

`App.js`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Environment Variables in a Create React App on Netlify</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and commit to your repo.
        </p>
        <p>NODE_ENV value is "{process.env.NODE_ENV}"</p>
        <p>CUSTOM_ENV_VAR value is "{process.env.CUSTOM_ENV_VAR}"</p>
        <p>REACT_APP_CUSTOM_ENV_VAR value is "{process.env.REACT_APP_CUSTOM_ENV_VAR}"</p>
        <p>TOML_ENV_VAR value is "{process.env.TOML_ENV_VAR}"</p>
        <p>REACT_APP_TOML_ENV_VAR value is "{process.env.REACT_APP_TOML_ENV_VAR}"</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Produces the following at https://netlify-cra-env-vars.netlify.com/:
[image]

### Setting Environment Variables in site settings on `Netlify.com`

In `app.netlify.com`, `CUSTOM_ENV_VAR` and `REACT_APP_CUSTOM_ENV_VAR` were set as follows:
[image]

### Setting Environment Variables in `netlify.toml`

The [`netlify.toml`](https://github.com/talves/netlify-cra-env-vars/blob/master/netlify.toml) environment variables were set as:

```
[build]
  command = "yarn build"
  publish = "build"

[context.production.environment]
  TOML_ENV_VAR = "From netlify.toml"
  REACT_APP_TOML_ENV_VAR = "From netlify.toml (REACT_APP_)"
```

#### **[Extra]** Setting environment variables in `.env`

You could set environment variables in a `.env` file at the root of your project and commit to your repository. The following is available with `react-scripts@1.1.0` and higher which takes your `version` value of your `package.json` file.

`.env`

```
REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version
```

***Note:*** the version (and many other [npm exposed environment variables](https://gist.github.com/moos/4635bda5b04dc8113d8ea7ee974cabc2)) can be accessed.
***Do not put secret keys into your repository.***

Comment: Have you been able to access the Netlify provided variables, like COMMIT_REF?

Comment: Figured out my above question. CRA overrides `process.env` to provide the `REACT_APP` variables. To access the netlify variables, you have to rename them in your build script like so:  `REACT_APP_COMMIT_REF="$COMMIT_REF"`

Comment:  Right. During build the client app code will only have access to them if they start with `REACT_APP_`

Comment: Regarding ntl env vars, they can be accessed from a client OR/AND server js file. They are location independent. However, they need to be prepared during built process and therefore need to be prefixed with `process.env.<envvar>`. Am I right?

Answer (score 8):

While there are many ways to accomplish this, the simplest way I found to get Netlify Environment variables into my React app was to create an `.env` file at the root of the project with the following content:

```sh
# React Environment Variables
# https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#expanding-environment-variables-in-env

# Netlify Environment Variables
# https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/#environment-variables
REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version
REACT_APP_REPOSITORY_URL=$REPOSITORY_URL
REACT_APP_BRANCH=$BRANCH
REACT_APP_PULL_REQUEST=$PULL_REQUEST
REACT_APP_HEAD=$HEAD
REACT_APP_COMMIT_REF=$COMMIT_REF
REACT_APP_CONTEXT=$CONTEXT
REACT_APP_REVIEW_ID=$REVIEW_ID
REACT_APP_INCOMING_HOOK_TITLE=$INCOMING_HOOK_TITLE
REACT_APP_INCOMING_HOOK_URL=$INCOMING_HOOK_URL
REACT_APP_INCOMING_HOOK_BODY=$INCOMING_HOOK_BODY
REACT_APP_URL=$URL
REACT_APP_DEPLOY_URL=$DEPLOY_URL
REACT_APP_DEPLOY_PRIME_URL=$DEPLOY_PRIME_URL
```

Display all these env variables by placing this in a visible components:

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(process.env, undefined, 2)}</pre>
```

**Important!** You will need to re-start (or re-build) the app in order to set these environment variables anytime they change.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to test/accomplish this in create-react-app is

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "export REACT_APP_COMMIT_REF=\"$COMMIT_REF\" && react-scripts build",
    
  }
  ...
}
```

**config.ts**

```
if (!process.env.REACT_APP_COMMIT_REF) {
    throw new Error("`REACT_APP_COMMIT_REF` not set")
}

console.log("REACT_APP_COMMIT_REF is", process.env.REACT_APP_COMMIT_REF)

export const config = {
    GIT_SHA: process.env.REACT_APP_COMMIT_REF,
}
```

Thanks to Netlify's automatic deploy preview, you can verify commit SHA is shown in the application console.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I added my environment variables from React to Netlify:

1. On Netlify's website go to your app's page.
2. Click on `Site settings`.
   [image]
3. Go to `Build & deploy`.

[image]

4. Scroll down to `Environment variables` and add all variables you have in your `.env` file in React.

[image]

5. Redeploy your app.