# How can I set environment variables on netlify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, email-client, react-typescript

I have a netlify react app. which is connected to my github. I'm using emailjs for receiving the messages from whoever reaches to my app.

emailjs deals with three ids 'SERVICE_ID', 'TEMPLATE_ID' and 'USER_ID'. But I don't wanna use them openly in my component js file.

Driver Function

```
  function sendEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    //This is important, i'm not sure why, but the email won't send without it

    emailjs.sendForm(SERVICE_ID, TEMPLATE_ID, e.target, USER_ID)
      .then((result) => {
          window.location.reload()  //This is if you still want the page to reload (since e.preventDefault() cancelled that behavior)
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  }
```

Comment: This feels very much like you haven't set environment variables properly. Your comment on Hamza Jadid's answer also notes that the error is shouting about a missing environment variable. You should make sure that you're using [Netlify's environment variables](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/) properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use Build Environment Variables in Netlify with Create-React-App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542840/can-i-use-build-environment-variables-in-netlify-with-create-react-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set env variables on netlify. Please have a check the below images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you're referring to environment variables, in order to test that out locally it will vary per the stack you use for creating the app, if you use react create app you can create a .env file in the root of your project and populate the values

```
REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID ="your_value"
REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID ="your_value"
REACT_APP_USER_ID ="your_value"
```

Don't forget to exclude this file from git, to avoid pushing secrets in your repo. to do that add this to your .gitignore

```
.env
```

After that you can call the variables in your code using the [process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) like this:

`process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID`

Now modify the code:

```
  function sendEmail(e) {
   // Your code

   emailjs.sendForm(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID, process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID, e.target, process.env.REACT_APP_USER_ID)
   // your promise
  }
```

To make that work in netlify you would have to add the variable in  your netlify project, follow this section to do that: https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/#declare-variables

As you noted I added the prefix REACT_APP_, this is because react create app does this:

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with
> REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to
> avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could
> have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require
> you to restart the development server if it is running.

If you are using gatsby or nextjs the env variables naming convention might change so please be aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Adding env variables to react app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

You can create a `.env` in your root dir and add your keys, api end points,... inside of it.

Comment: I've tried the same and added it to .gitignore. It was working fine in my local machine but in the live netlify server it is giving me the following error 
`index.js:29 POST https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send-form 400
The user ID is required. To find this ID, visit https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin/integration`

Comment: Then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542840/can-i-use-build-environment-variables-in-netlify-with-create-react-app

Comment: Did you rebuild the application after adding the environment variables